# How can I add an image as a texture that looks exactly like a background image (full brightness and unaffected by lighting)

Tags: rendering, light, image

I recognize that background images can't be rendered because they are made for reference only, but every time I try to add an image as a texture, it comes out completely washed out, I assume due to the scene lighting.  Even when I import it as shadeless, the colors are still completely inaccurate.  How can I add an image that renders as completely accurate to the original image and is unaffected by light?  For reference, in the image I attached, the image on the left is the image as a texture and the image on the right is the reference.
[image]

The image is a company logo, so the colors have to be perfect.  The idea is that the laptop will open up and cover the logo, so it also can't have any sort of "Show in front" type of thing that you can do with background images.

I'm sure I can't be the first person to do something like this, but I can't find the right answer anywhere.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could composite the logo in at the render stage.

Comment: Check if switching from *Filmic* to *Default* in *Color management* section helps

Comment: Go to the shading tab and connect your image texture directly to the material output with no shader (BSDF) in between.

Answer (score 1):

[image: The Result]
This is the original browser window with the Blender render window on-top showing the default cube rendered over original page, which was clipped as an image.

[image: The node setup]
And this is the node setup that created it.

Comment: I can confirm this works: https://i.imgur.com/B5UUz8t.png just for clarity, `Screen.PNG` is the *Input > Image Node*